# using one ASyncTask for several times Simultaneously

Tags: android, android-asynctask, download

I have a program  with one button click, when clicked, 4 Downloads should executed Simultaneously. I use `ASyncTask` class for this purpose with `for` iterator:

```
for(int i=0;i<downloadCounts;i++){
new DownloadTask().execute(url[i]);
}
```

but in running, only one download executed and all 4 progressbars show that single download. 
 I want to download 4 downloads in same time. how can I do?

**for more details**, my download manager, get a link and divide it to 4 chunks according to file size. then with above `for` iterator , command it to run 4 parts download with this class:

```
private class DownloadChunks extends AsyncTask<Long,String,String>{

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        setStatusText(-1);
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Long... params) {
        long s1 = params[0];
        long s2 = params[1];

        int count;
        try{
            URL url = new URL(urlString);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Range", "bytes=" + s1 + "-" + s2);
            connection.connect();
            len2 = connection.getContentLength();

            InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream(),8192);
            File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/nuhexxxx");
            if(!file.exists())file.mkdirs();
            OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(file+"/nuhe1.mp3");
            byte[] data = new byte[1024];
            long total = 0;
            while ((count= input.read(data))!=-1){
                total += count;
                publishProgress(""+(int)((total*100)/len2));
                output.write(data,0,count);
            }

            output.flush();
            output.close();
            input.close();
            counter++;


        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);

        setStatusText(Integer.parseInt(values[0]));

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        Log.e("This part is downloaded", "..." + len2 + " start with: " + counter);
    }
}
```

All logs shows that every thing is OK and file is completely downloaded. but each chunk download separate and in order. I want to download chunks Simultaneously

Comment: According to your code, it seems to me that four downloads should be started. However, pls post some more code so that we could help.

Comment: @RuchiraRandana more details added

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of just call the `.execute()` method of your AsyncTask, use this logic to achieve what you want:

```
if( Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB ) {   
    new MyAsyncTask().executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, params);
} else {
    new MyAsyncTask().execute(params);
}
```

Check more info from the [official documentation of AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Comment: this is great and work. thank you. but all of my progress bars show same percents. do you know any resolve?

Comment: But isn't that accurate?

Comment: Yes. AsyncTasks works greatly. But I cant assign independent 'ProgressBar.setProgress(int)' to those.

Comment: I'd like to say your implementation, where you execute the tasks.